# I want to use devise to edit within the show page of a User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, custom-routes

In my show page for my User I have a edit profile tab that is contained in the profile. I made a Devise controller that I build custom routes with. My issue is now when im within 'users/show/:id' it shows the edit page.  Should I copy the devise edit page view to my show view?

My routes.rb is set like so.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_scope :teacher do
    get "/teachers/:id" => "devise/registrations#edit" #removed

  end
  devise_for :teachers, controllers: { registrations: 'teachers/registrations' }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
```

This is my controller

```
class Teachers::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create],
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  #GET /resource/sign_up
   def new
     super
   end

   def sign_up_params
        params.require(:teacher).permit(:name, :avatar, :email, :password)
   end

   #POST /resource/
   def create
    super
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
     super
   end
```

A visual of what I am trying to do is below[image]

As you can see I have a tab set up to edit the proDfile in page.
Do I just copy the edit view into the fields of the show where I created the edit tab?

**UPDATE**

As I render the form into the show page it gives me this error.

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Teachers#show
Showing /home/malik/Desktop/NYCDA/docs/week9/teachers-pet/app/views/teachers/show.html.erb where line #163 raised:

Missing partial devise/registrations/_edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

Comment: You should be able to render the form and use it in the show page(or any page for that matter) are you facing any problems when you save the edit form?

Comment: I would check [HERE](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) and see if it is useful.  What route goes to the devise edit form?

Comment: The route is within the user/registrations folder. I want to have that page custom view into the show page for the user.